# How to fix terminal title-bar icon in Ubuntu?

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-terminal, titlebar, macbuntu

I applied a Mac OS theme to my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

The new icons are coming properly in titlebar of all applications except for terminal and gedit like below.

[image]

You can see that between the minimise-maximise buttons and the title of my terminal there's a big useless image which is the new theme's icon.

How to fix this?

Comment: Nope, that would be changing the icon theme itself. @pomsky

Comment: In that case report a bug to the theme's maintainers.

Comment: Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1770507. Nag the developers over there, or recompile mutter for yourself without the offending patch.